# Recursividade em Fila Java

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Meu professor diz que é uma péssima prática de programação, passar a variável que nos interessa como parâmetro de um método recursivo, ex:

```
    int getMaior(Celula i, int maiorV)
```

Ele diz que é melhor fazer o seguinte método:

```
    public int getMaior(){
        return getMaior(primeiro.prox);
    }

    public int getMaior(Celula i){


        if(i!=null){

            if(i.elemento>maior) maior= i.elemento ; 
            maior=getMaior(i.prox);
        }

        return maior;
    }
```

Porém, se a variável maior não for global, esse método não funciona.

Já tentei também fazer:

```
    public int getMaior(){
        return getMaior(primeiro.prox);
    }

    public int getMaior(Celula i){
        int maior=Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        if(i!=null){

            if(i.elemento>maior) maior= i.elemento ; 
            maior=getMaior(i.prox);
        }

        return maior;
    }
```

E não tive êxito. Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Isto é fila ou é lista? Porque o conceito de fila significa retirar do começo e colocar no fim. Se você está inspecionando qualquer coisa no meio, então o seu problema deixou de ser uma fila e degenerou em uma lista.

Comment: Além disso, a sua pergunta está um pouco confusa em uma coisa: Cadê o código da classe célula?

Answer (score 1):

Use um laço para isso ao invés de recursão:

```
public int getMaior() {
    int maior = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    if (primeiro == null) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (Celula i = primeiro; i != null; i = i.prox) {
        int v = i.elemento;
        if (v > maior) maior = v;
    }

    return v;
}
```

O motivo da recursão ser uma má prática no seu caso é que ela consome espaço na pilha de chamadas. Para listas de células muito longas, isso daí pode acabar causando um `StackOverflowError`. Mesmo se não causar, informações sobre todas as células vão se empilhando na pilha de execução, enquanto que na versão com um laço, informações de apenas uma célula são mantidas na memória.

Um outro detalhe é que ressalto que o conceito de fila significa retirar do começo e colocar no fim e mais nada. Se você está inspecionando qualquer coisa no meio para encontrar o maior elemento, então você está violando o conceito de fila e a sua implementação se degenera em uma lista. Usar recursão ao invés de iteração não resolve esse problema, apenas o deixa mais escondido.

Por fim, variável global sempre é uma má prática de programação (lembrando que variável e constante são conceitos diferentes). Evite variáveis globais ao máximo.

Se você por qualquer motivo realmente precisa usar recursão, então faça assim:

```
public int getMaior(Celula i) {
    if (i == null) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maior = getMaior(i.prox);
    int v = i.elemento;
    return v > maior ? v : maior;
}
```

Em linguagens de programação que têm recursão de cauda, onde o compilador ou interpretador otimiza a recursão substituindo-a por uma iteração (não é o caso do Java, mas vamos supor que fosse), nesse caso a sua abordagem original seria a melhor:

```
public int getMaior(Celula i) {
    return getMaior(i, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}

private int getMaior(Celula i, int maior) {
    if (i == null) return maior;
    int v = i.elemento;
    return v > maior ? getMaior(i.prox, v) : getMaior(i.prox, maior);
}
```